# How to hide "Shipping" label from Woocommerce cart page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, html

I am trying to hide/unset Woocommerce "Shipping"label from the cart page in order to have more width for the shipping calculator. Is there any way to hide only the word "Shipping"from the table, without losing subtotals and total price (see pic after)?

any tip would be great!!

thanks a lot..

[image: before]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly because of your theme you can change the theme and see if gets resolved. If you want to use same theme you need to add custom CSS  for "shipping" class or id. Based on your preference you can either hide or decrease the width for "shipping"